# Error binding parameter 0: probably unsupported type

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code, but I keep getting the:

```
error "binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type".
```

Here is my code:

```
last = 'EBERT'

sakila = connect("sakila.db")
res = sakila.execute("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE last_name = ?",[(last,)])

for row in res:
    print(row)
```

When I have it where '`EBERT`' is in the query and not set to a variable, it works fine, so I know it's a problem with the tuple syntax or something. I've tried it without the brackets, with a second variable for `first_name`, with and without a separately defined cursor, and basically every method I can think of, and I've researched for hours but have gotten nowhere, so any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: the lines and indentation is all fine in my code btw, it just got messed up in the post.

Comment: Also I can't get the fetchall thing to work. I have res.fetchall() but it only gives me an empty list and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nested lists, tuples are used for [`executemany`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany), not for [`execute`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15).

Pass a flat list (or tuple) that contians parameters.

```
res = sakila.execute(
    "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE last_name = ?",
    (last,))
```

or

```
res = sakila.execute(
    "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE last_name = ?",
    [last])
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked well. do you know how to work fetchall() so that res.fetchall() doesn't create an empty list?

Comment: @user3345626, Did you call `fetchall` after you iterated `res`? Once it is iterated, it is exausted. You need to execute the query again. Simply removing the `for` loop will solve you problem.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error, sorted out that my data type was mismatched. I then converted it into string;

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?);''', (str(data[0]), ))
```

and it worked fine. Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I run this code,

```
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ?', (username, ))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()

    cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Course(title) VALUES (?)', (course, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Course WHERE title = ?', (course, ))
    course_id = cur.fetchone()

    print(user_id, course_id, role)
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Member(user_id, course_id, role) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (user_id, course_id, role))
```

the problem was that cur.fetchone() returned a list with one element not an integer value. so you need to add the square brackets to access the element.

```
 cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User(name) VALUES (?)', (username, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ?', (username, ))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Course(title) VALUES (?)', (course, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Course WHERE title = ?', (course, ))
    course_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    print(user_id, course_id, role)
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Member(user_id, course_id, role) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (user_id, course_id, role))
```