# Python: Populate SQLite-Table using data from a text file - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

The problem is that I can't get the data from the text file to write to the database.
The text file is organized line by line ex:

```
John Doe 012-345-6789
```

As you can see, I've split the text and have all the categories straightened out.
But keep getting errors like `InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably un supported type` or something about writing 47 entries to one field.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('phoneNumbers.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS People ')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE People (firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, phonenumber TEXT)')


########

file = open('phoneNumbers.txt', 'r')

try:
    file = open('phoneNumbers.txt', 'r')
except:
    print "File not found"

data = file.read()
data = data.split()

for line in data:
    first = data[0::3]
    last = data [1::3]
    num = data [2::3]


cur.execute('INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, phonenumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (first, last, num))
conn.commit()

cur.execute('SELECT firstname, lastname, phonenumber FROM People')
for row in cur:
    print row

conn.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error binding parameter 0: probably unsupported type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981709/error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. you are using the name `file` for your file, this is a built in name and you should rename it
2. you are opening the file twice, once before the try once in the try
3. Your actual problem:

`first`, `last` and `num` are lists and `execute` cannot use lists as parameters.
There is an `executeMany`but I do not like it in this case.

**EDIT**
Even slicker is reading line by line and using the `with` command.

```
with open('phoneNumbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, phonenumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (data[0], data[1], data[2]))
        if 'str' in line:
            break
```

**Original**
I would use a for with an `index` and then execute the INSERT in the loop like that.

```
try:
    numbersFile = open('phoneNumbers.txt', 'r')
except:
    print "File not found"

data = numbersFile.read()
data = data.split()

for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
    first = data[i]
    last = data[i+1]
    num = data[i+2]
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, phonenumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (first, last, num))

conn.commit()
```