# Sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to update my user rank table where the username = ? and the FlashcardID = ?. I changed the username from a ? to a real value and it worked but soon as i changed it back it gave me an error.

Here is my code -

```
connection.execute ("UPDATE UserRank SET CorrectScore = CorrectScore + 1 WHERE User = ? AND FlashcardID = ?",(self.username, self.id[self.currentQ]))
```

And the error i get is as followed -

> Sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably
>   unsupported type.

Editing it to this -

```
connection.execute ("UPDATE UserRank SET CorrectScore = CorrectScore + 1 WHERE User = '?' AND FlashcardID = ?",(self.username, self.id[self.currentQ]))
```

And the error with the changes are -

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: It is established somewhere in the comments for @Evhz's answer that `self.id[self.currentQ]` is a tuple. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981709/error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was calling a tuple, therefore to fix it all I did was put the tuple into a new variable called self.fid, and then it worked.

```
self.fid = self.id[self.currentQ][0]

connection.execute ("UPDATE UserRank SET CorrectScore = CorrectScore + 1 WHERE User = ? AND FlashcardID = ? ",([self.username]+[self.fid])
```

Answer (score 0):

Update

Reading the comments you are trying to compare an integer `123` with the username. That's why it cant bind parameter 1.

As suggested in comments, review the `self.username` field. 
In case you need to compare it,

use the first query (which was just fine), but cast the `123` to string:

```
connection.execute ("UPDATE UserRank SET CorrectScore = CorrectScore + 1 WHERE User = ? AND FlashcardID = ?",( str(self.username), self.id[self.currentQ]))
```

It might work for you like that.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary for parameters used this way.

Comment: I wasn't sure too, @Joseph otherwise check the params before the query.

Comment: @Joseph `print(repr(self.username))` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: @Joseph you could update the question with the new error.

Comment: @khelwood it returns '123'

Comment: @Joseph What about `print(repr(self.id[self.currentQ]))` ?

Comment: @khelwood  it gives back (0,)

Comment: @Joseph check the updated answer with the `str()` cast. Maybe it works.

Comment: @Joseph That is the problem. Your `self.id[self.currentQ]` is a tuple, not an integer.

Comment: @khelwood how would i convet it to an int cause when i do int it or str it comes back with the same error

Comment: If you just want to unwrap the tuple, you could use `self.id[self.currentQ][0]`